# PHP/Postman - How to populate the $Get

Tags: php, get, postman

I am trying to do a Get request with Postman to a PHP script. But it doesn't seem to populate the $_GET array? Why is this happening?

http://localhost/download.php/game

```
<?php
$config = (object) ['localhost' => 'localhost', 'dbusername' => 'root', 'dbpassword' => '', 'dbname' => 'test', 'tablename' => 'tablename'];

echo "Succesfull request";
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["game"]);
if (isset($_GET['game'])) {
    echo "It's a get request!";
}
```

Comment: Because `$_GET` is populated in the url by having something such as; `localhost/download.php?game=X` not slashed as a sub page would be

Comment: Do you have RewriteRules in place that tell your server that `download.php/game` is in fact something like `download.php?section=game`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure whether $_GET['game'] is empty or not try using var_dump($_GET['game'] to first check the content of the array. Also you will need to include the get parameter within the link somewhat like this: yourdomain/download.php?game=variable. Also change your double quotation marks when trying to access $_GET to single marks.